# Modify dataframe with complex values into a new multiindexed dataframe with real and imaginary parts using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-numbers

I have a dataframe with complex numbers as shown below,

```
>>>df.head()
         96               98
1   3.608719+23.596415j 3.782185+22.818022j
2   7.239342+28.990936j 6.801471+26.978671j
3   3.671441+23.73544j  3.842973+22.940337j
4   3.935188+24.191112j 4.063692+23.269834j
5   3.544675+23.561207j 3.852818+22.951067j
```

I am trying to create a new multiindexed dataframe out of it as below,

```
             96                     98  
       R           X           R           X
1   3.608719    23.596415   3.782185    22.818022
2   7.239342    28.990936   6.801471    26.978671
3   3.671441    23.73544    3.842973    22.940337
4   3.935188    24.191112   4.063692    23.269834
5   3.544675    23.561207   3.852818    22.951067
```

I have tried splitting them into real & imaginary dataframes and then merge/concat them, but was not successful.

Comment: All are complex numbers?

Comment: Yes..all the values are complex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.concat([df.apply(lambda x: x.real), df.apply(lambda x: x.imag)], 
               axis=1, 
               keys=('R','X')) \
       .swaplevel(0,1,1) \
       .sort_index(1)
print (df)
         96                   98           
          R          X         R          X
1  3.608719  23.596415  3.782185  22.818022
2  7.239342  28.990936  6.801471  26.978671
3  3.671441  23.735440  3.842973  22.940337
4  3.935188  24.191112  4.063692  23.269834
5  3.544675  23.561207  3.852818  22.951067
```

Another solution:

```
a = df.values
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ['R','X'], df.columns])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([a.real, a.imag], axis=1), columns=mux)
        .swaplevel(0,1,1)
        .sort_index(1)
print (df1)
         96                   98           
          R          X         R          X
0  3.608719  23.596415  3.782185  22.818022
1  7.239342  28.990936  6.801471  26.978671
2  3.671441  23.735440  3.842973  22.940337
3  3.935188  24.191112  4.063692  23.269834
4  3.544675  23.561207  3.852818  22.951067
```

Comment: Glad can help! If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.

Comment: `from_product` and `swaplevel` are new one to me - but then this is a non trivial operation.  I would have used `pandasql` or more likely `pyspark` since `sql` is a lot more comfortable for something like this

Comment: np.real(x) instead of x.real worked for me:)