# Pandas split only columns with complex data into real- and imaginary part

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-numbers

I am new to pandas and am trying to work with Dataframes containing a mix of complex-valued numerical data and some other stuff (strings etc.)

A stripped down version of what I am talking about:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([
        [0.1 + 1j, 0.2 + 0.2j, 0.2, 0.1j, "label_a", 1],
        [0.1 + 1j, 0.5 + 1.2j, 0.5, 1.0j, "label_b", 3],
    ])
columns = np.array([-12, -10, 10, 12, "label", "number"])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=columns)
```

For the purpose of saving and reading to disk persistently, I need to split the complex values into their real- and imaginary, since apparently none of the relevant disk formats (hdf5, parquet, etc.) support complex numbers.

Now if the dataframe were to contain *only* complex numbers, I could do this by introducing a multi-index, which is what other questions already cover (e.g. [Modify dataframe with complex values into a new multiindexed dataframe with real and imaginary parts using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720253/modify-dataframe-with-complex-values-into-a-new-multiindexed-dataframe-with-real)).

```py
# save to file
pd.concat(
    [df.apply(np.real), df.apply(np.imag)],
    axis=1,
    keys=("R", "I"),
).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1).to_parquet(file)

# read from file
df = pd.read_parquet(file)
real = df.loc[:, (slice(None), "R")].droplevel(1, axis=1)
imag = df.loc[:, (slice(None), "I")].droplevel(1, axis=1)
df = real + 1j * imag
```

However this approach breaks down in the presence of e.g. string fields.

I am currently doing this by splitting the dataframe into one containing only complex numbers (i.e. the first four columns here) and the rest. Then I apply the above approach on the former, merge with the latter and save to file. This works, but isn't particularly nice, especially when the columns aren't ordered that neatly.

I was hoping that someone with more pandas experience would have a simpler way of achieving that. In case it matters: In terms of performance, I don't care about writes, but I do care about reading from file back into a dataframe.

Comment: do you know which columns contain the complex numbers?

Comment: I do, and currently those are also just the first N (as opposed to these columns being scattered through the dataframe). I am okay with assuming that since I can probably reorder that easily if push comes to shove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the columns which you know are complex, and the other ones independently. Add a dummy second level for the other columns:

##### Writing

```
N = 4
cols = df.columns[:N] # or define an explicit list of names

# ensure the type is complex
# you might need to adjust to other types (np.complex128, np.complex256…)
tmp = df[cols].astype(np.complex64)

(pd.concat(
    # slice the complex columns
    # NB. using a more efficient way to get the real/imaginary parts
    [pd.DataFrame(np.real(tmp), index=tmp.index, columns=cols),
     pd.DataFrame(np.imag(tmp), index=tmp.index, columns=cols),
    ],
    axis=1,
    keys=("R", "I"),
          )
   # add the other columns
   .join(pd.concat({None: df[df.columns.difference(cols)]}, axis=1))
   .swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)
   .to_parquet('test_pqt')
)
```

##### Reading

```
# read from file
df = pd.read_parquet('test_pqt')

N = 4
cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0)[:N] # or define an explicit list of names

other_cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0).difference(cols)

real = df.loc[:, (cols, "R")].droplevel(1, axis=1)
imag = df.loc[:, (cols, "I")].droplevel(1, axis=1)
df = (real + 1j * imag).join(df.droplevel(1, axis=1)[other_cols])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        -10       -12   10   10   12   12    label number
0  0.2+0.2j  0.1+1.0j  0.0  0.2  0.1  0.0  label_a      1
1  0.5+1.2j  0.1+1.0j  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  label_b      3
```

Comment: That's really neat! Just out of curiosity, do you think this would scale well to large dataframes? I will be testing that soon and have been wondering whether this whole split/join approach is expected to be performant (not that there seems to be a way to do it differently)

Comment: @Banana honestly I don't know, I tried to improve the conversion to real/imaginary by using numpy directly, but you have to test it on your real data. Let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tmp = df[cols].astype(np.complex64)
for col in tmp:

    col1 = col + "_1"
    col2 = col + "_2"
    df[[col1, col2]] = df[col].str.split('+',expand = True)
```